# Build(s) list empty when trying to "attach" build to Release

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I hope anyone here has experienced this problem before and can tell me something about it.

I've been in contact with Apple Developer support, but they are unable to help me so far and i am desperate to get this version live.

Ever since Apple pushed their new layout for iTunesConnect/App Store Connect I am unable to select a build to attach to a release i want to submit for review. The box shows :

```
" Upload your builds using one of several tools. See Upload Tools "
```

This is basically the default text when no builds are available; if we check the Developer tools in chrome you can see the API call to retrieve builds gives a HTTP 500 error: (I redacted my appId)

```
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/iris/v1/builds?filter[app]=<APPID>&filter[preReleaseVersion.platform]=IOS&filter[isAppStoreCandidate]=true&filter[processingState]=VALID&include=icons,preReleaseVersion,buildBundles&limit=10
```

Response:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "status": "500",
        "code": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
        "title": "An unexpected error occurred.",
        "detail": "An unexpected error occurred on the server side. If this issue continues, contact us at https://developer.apple.com/contact/."
    }]
}
```

We have multiple apps but only one of them is experiencing this behavior, i can submit the others just fine. The build(s) are correctly being uploaded and are available in Testflight.

I have been in contact with Apple Support; but it seems they are set on giving me the standard responses make a video of the problem etc.

Thought i'd try my luck here as the issue is becoming more pressing from "above", maybe someone has any idea where i can start trying to resolve this issue from my side?

Comment: Not sure how we can help you, if even Apple is not able. Did you try a different browser / session?

Comment: I was hoping someone had a similar experience and knew some setting perhaps, or something to help this issue along. Apple Support is methodical but slow. 

Multiple of my Colleagues have this issue on different machines/browsers.

Comment: I don't think anecdotal knowledge is very helpful in this case. There are some issues with App Store Connect and the only party so resolve this really is Apple.